# Fire event inside handler

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to fire event inside event handler in this way (with no luck)...

```html
<div id="test">
 <button onclick="this.dispatchEvent(new Event('btn-a'))">A</button>
 <button onclick="this.dispatchEvent(new Event('btn-b'))">B</button>
</div>
```

```js
let test = document.getElementById("test")
test.addEventListener('btn-a', () => { console.log("A") })
test.addEventListener('btn-b', () => { console.log("B") })
```

Is it possible, and if it is, how to do it properly ? Without jQuery please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default events created by [Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/Event) don’t bubble, due to that the event in your code will only fire one the `button`.

But you attache the listener to the parent of the `button`, so the event callback won’t be called in this case.

You could set `bubbles` to `true` and it should work:

```
new Event('btn-b', {bubbles:true})
```

Comment: Thank, you for this answer. It works in my real world case, when i'm trying to catch events on the shadowRoot of the custom web component. This helps me to work with actions rather than separate events.

Answer (score -1):

The event listener is attached to the parent rather than the button. You should be dispatching the event on the [`parentElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentElement):

```js
let test = document.getElementById("test")
test.addEventListener('btn-a', () => { console.log("A") })
test.addEventListener('btn-b', () => { console.log("B") })
```

```html
<div id="test">
 <button onclick="this.parentElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('btn-a'))">A</button>
 <button onclick="this.parentElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('btn-b'))">B</button>
</div>
```

Alternatively you can set the third parameter in [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to `true`:

```js
let test = document.getElementById("test")
test.addEventListener('btn-a', () => { console.log("A") }, true)
test.addEventListener('btn-b', () => { console.log("B") }, true)
```

```html
<div id="test">
 <button onclick="this.dispatchEvent(new Event('btn-a'))">A</button>
 <button onclick="this.dispatchEvent(new Event('btn-b'))">B</button>
</div>
```

Comment: `Alternatively you can set the third parameter in addEventListener to true to enable event bubbling` the third parameter won’t have an effect on whether the event bubbles or not. It controls if the event callback is called in the capturing or bubbling phase.

Answer (score -1):

Why dont initial the onclick with javascript too?

Then you see what is your problem :) `this` will refere to the button, but you are listening on the wrapper  div.

Try this one:

```
<div id="test">
 <button data-event="btn-a">A</button>
 <button data-event="btn-b">B</button>
</div>
```

JS:

```
let test = document.getElementById("test")
test.addEventListener('btn-a', () => { console.log("A") })
test.addEventListener('btn-b', () => { console.log("B") })

let buttons = test.querySelectorAll('button');

buttons.forEach(button => 
    button.addEventListener('click', e => {
       test.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent(e.target.dataset.event));
    });
);
```